# How to format date coming from the database in angular

Tags: angular, date

I would like to know if one can filter/format ngFor date (coming from the database). I have date format: "2017-11-02 12:13:14" in the database but I want to show just "2017-11-02" in my ngFor table. Is this possible?

```
<tr *ngFor="let myCar of cars>
            <td>{{myCar.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.registered}}</td> //can I format retrieved date here?
</tr>
```

I just want to know if I can remove the time and only show the date to users. I am not sure if PIPE can work.

Comment: You can either use Angular's built in datePipe or build a custom pipe the trims of the time.

Comment: the date from database is type of string I think. right?

Comment: @Pleasure you can use angular pipes as `<tr *ngFor="let myCar of cars>
            <td>{{myCar.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.registered | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
</tr>`

Comment: @AmirChristian yes..

Comment: If you confirm myCar.registered is string then, you don't need to format it again but can use `slice` to take out of string you want like "2017-11-02" from there easily.

Comment: Simply use the date pipe. Or define a custom pipe and invoke it over here.

Comment: @77792, my first attempt to solve the issue was the pipe approch but does not work for me. .slice works fine.

Comment: @Pleasure Good to hear that!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `.slice` like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let myCar of cars>
    <td>{{myCar.name}}</td>
    <td>{{myCar.registered.slice(0, 10)}}</td>
</tr>
```

no need to format it again

Comment: Bad practice when you have Angular pipes

Comment: The slice() works pretty fine. I have read more about slice here now:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: @NikNik it is important to solve one's problem easily but not that way to solve it here I think. And for now this is working fine.

Comment: Great to hear that it works and it's really cool that you are helping other people but... 
If you are using Angular, it's really great if you use the best practice, otherwise, use raw javascript :) This is just a tip to work better

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74cpp1?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```html
<tr *ngFor="let myCar of cars>
            <td>{{myCar.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.registered | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://momentjs.com/

Set the local language in the app.component.ts

```
moment.locale('pt-BR');
```

Create a service (fx `date-utils.service.ts`) to format the date:

```
public formatDate(inputDate) { return moment(inputdate).format(); }
```

Then you can use it in your ts file:

```
this.registered = dateUtilsService.formatDate(registered);
```